# How to construct isosceles triangle from these given data

Tags: geometric-construction

How do I construct an isosceles triangle ABC (|AC| = |BC| = a), given $a-v_a$ and the angle $α$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking of starting with the construction of a smaller triangle where one side is given as $a−v_a$, and an angle of $180-α$. However, I'm not sure how to determine the third element.

Comment: $\upsilon_a$, what does that mean?

Comment: $v_a$ is altitude to side a

Comment: Could you edit your post to include these elements?

Comment: The following hint is based on the assumption that you have  an isosceles triangle, with the two equal sides of length $~a.~$  Denote one of these sides as $~A.~$ I am then assuming that the angle $~\alpha~$ is opposite $~A~$ and that an altitude $~V_a,~$ runs from angle $~\alpha~$ to side $~A.~$  This implies that one of the angles adjacent to side $~A~$ is $~\beta = (180^\circ - 2\alpha),~$ and that $$\frac{V_a}{a} = \sin(\beta).$$  This allows you to construct an equation $~E = a \times F,~$ where $~E,F~$ are known, with $~E = a - V_a.~$  Thus $~a = \dfrac{E}{F}.$